# nvidia_deeplearningexamples_tacotron2 :RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device function

Tags: pytorch

Set up runtime: python3 and GPU.

Run the [code](https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/pytorch.github.io/blob/master/assets/hub/nvidia_deeplearningexamples_tacotron2.ipynb) step by step.
I only successfully run the code at first time.

After that, when run the below part, occured "RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device function"

```
sequence = np.array(tacotron2.text_to_sequence(text, ['english_cleaners']))[None, :]
sequence = torch.from_numpy(sequence).to(device='cuda', dtype=torch.int64)

with torch.no_grad():
    _, mel, _, _ = tacotron2.infer(sequence)
    audio = waveglow.infer(mel)
audio_numpy = audio[0].data.cpu().numpy()
rate = 22050
```

Do you know the root cause? And does the pre-trained model be run on local CPU?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, you can solve this issue by adding 
!pip install torch==1.1.0 torchvision==0.3.0
before import torch
in https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/pytorch.github.io/blob/master/assets/hub/nvidia_deeplearningexamples_tacotron2.ipynb

[image: Adding import]